# MYSQL select from 3 or more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to make a MySQL query to show data from 3 diferents tables.

This is the table 1:

TABLE1

- id
- reference
- name
- email

This is the table 2:

TABLE2:

- id
- phone

This is the table 3:

TABLE3:

- id
- phone

I need to show all data from table1, and also the phone from table2 or table3, only if the id in table2 or table3 is the same number that is in the reference field in table1.

Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  t1.*
        COALESCE(t2.phone,t3.phone) phone
FROM    Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
        Table2 t2 ON t1.reference = t2.id LEFT JOIN
        Table3 t3 ON t1.reference = t3.id
```

Have a look at [COALESCE(value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and maybe [SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have an advice, modify your structure. There's no point in having different tables to hold different phone numbers. 
Here's something you can do:

```
table1( -- you should give it a better name
  id,
  -- reference, -- not needed now...
  name,
  email
);

phone_numbers(
  id,
  table1_id,
  phone
);
```

Now you can do something like:

```
SELECT    table1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(phone) 
FROM      table1 
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers ON table1.id = table1_id
GROUP BY  table1.id, name, email -- , whatever fields you have more on table1
```

Comment: Hi, I simplified the tables for this example, but I'm using diferents tables because is for the inscription in diferent courses, and the data is into the tables now, so I cannot modify the structure :/

Comment: @nmarti, Ok, but I can't guess that. From your question the only thing I can see is that your structure shouldn't be like that and modifying it would help. And I still believe there's no point in having two tables to hold the same type of data. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a phone from table2 or from table3.

Because these 2 tables have common columns, we can simplify this whole thing and think about these 2 tables as a single one, by using an UNION clause:

```
select table1.*, v.phone
  from table1
  inner join (select * from table2 
              union
             select * from table3) v on v.id = table1.reference
```

EDIT: corrected table names in the union

Comment: I think you should use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, because the OP needs *to show all data from table1, and also the phone from table2 or table3,* ***only if*** *the id in table2 or table3 is the same number that is in the reference field in table1*.

Comment: Also this solution can duplicate `table1` rows, if `table2` and `table3` contain rows with same `id`s and different phone numbers.

Comment: Yes, I predicated the case of showing duplicate table1 rows and I think it is ok to show 2 rows: one table1.*+table2.phone plus another table1.*+table3.phone

Comment: Actually I should probably agree with you. The OP has not stated (not yet) whether it is required to display one and only one phone number.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.reference = t2.ID
JOIN table3 t3
   ON t1.reference = t3.ID
```

Comment: don't worked, returns 0 items, the reference in table 1 will be in table2 or table3, not in the 2 tables at time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do CASE statement in select in mysql, but you can try a CASE statement as a column and join. Here is some sudo code.

```
SELECT  t1.*, CASE t2.phone IS NOT t3.phone THEN t3.phone ELSE t2.phone END CASE as PhoneNumber 
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.reference = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.reference = t3.id
```